# What frameworks and libraries are used in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

What frameworks and libraries are behind Chrome Developer Tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No frameworks, it is all in raw JS.

A few libraries are:

- [Codemirror](https://codemirror.net/)
- [Acorn](https://github.com/ternjs/acorn)
- [Gonzales](https://github.com/css/gonzales)

Not many are used for maximum control and performance. If you want to see how everything is put together, the full code can be seen on [github](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend) now.

Comment: Amazing that such a complex app is done is mostly in pure js! I just realized that Chrome Dev Tools can be used to inspect Chrome Dev Tools itself: while devtools window is in focus Command+Option+i (on OSX) would open a new devtools window for the original devtools window. Ctr+Shift+i should work on Linux/Windows.